# Selecting elements with Capybara

Tags: html, capybara

Let's say I have these three links:

```
<a href="/users/3">Show</a> 
<a href="/users/4">Show</a>
<a data-confirm="are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/users/4" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

How can I select the last one? I can't use the `text:` option because two links have the same text, and I can't use xpath to select via the href attribute because two links both have the some hrefs. Can I overlap parameters, and select via the href and the text? Or select via the href and the text and the presence of the attribute `data-method="delete"?`

Comment: Can you clarify which link you want? The last link is the "Destroy" link, which would have unique text (in the html sample).

Answer (score 1):

You can use data-method="delete" to select the last one like this ..

```
page.find(:css, "a[data-method='delete']").click()
```

If you want to select last anchor tag, please use this

```
page.find(:css, "a[data-method='delete']").click()
```